# Notepad++ REGEX Masking / Sanitise Data

Tags: regex, notepad++, sanitization, masking

There's a requirement to sanitise the Production file and hand it over then to a third party. The integrity / number of characters / digits should remain same.

```
<ADD1<4, Privet Drive, Scotland, EC12 5FL, UK<
```

In the above example, we need to mask number with 9, and Characters with X or x (based on case).

Target data should be.

```
<ADD1<9, Xxxxxx Xxxxx, Xxxxxxxx, XX99 9XX, XX<
```

Comment: Seems like, example from above post has been deleted automatically, as it was an address, with Digits, Characters, Spaces and Puncuation

Comment: The address was being interpreted as (broken) HTML, and therefore was not rendering.  I fixed it by changing it to code.

Comment: NP++ supports conditional replacement (if it's the one that uses boost::). Using that, it's a single regex and replacement.

Answer (score 1):

NP++ supposedly uses `boost::regex` engine.
And further, it apparently uses the boost-extended replacement format string.

This means you can put a conditional within the replacement string to test
which group matched, then replace accordingly.

syntax: `(?1yes:no)` says did group 1 match, do yes, else do no
syntax: `(?{1}yes:no)` same

If it's got boost::regex use

**update**

```
   only between <ADD1< and  <
```

find `(?:(?!^)\G|<ADD1<)[^a-zA-Z0-9<]*\K(?:([A-Z])|([a-z])|\d)`
replace `(?1X:(?2x:9))`

Note - select the replacement string format as Boost Extended
if it is not the default.

https://regex101.com/r/pJCsZa/1

Regex info

```
 (?:
      (?! ^ )
      \G                            # Start match where last left off
   |                              # or,
      <ADD1<                        # New start
 )
 [^a-zA-Z0-9<]*                # Optional non-letter or digit or <
 \K                            # Ignore matched characters up to here

 (?:                           # What's left, a letter or a digit
      ( [A-Z] )                     # (1)
   |  ( [a-z] )                     # (2)
   |  \d 
 )
```

Comment: Thanks @sln. This is really useful, but how to restrict the search and replacement between <ADD1< and <

Comment: Oh, I would also use the `\G` construct. Do you know how to do that ?

Comment: Thanks, it's brilliant. But, it's changing all A-Z to X and all digits to 9, including the ADD1 and everything in and around the <ADD1< and < delimiters

Comment: I've just changed the search to <ADD1<\K(?:([a-z])|([A-Z])|([0-9])|([^<]*))>. But, what should I put in Replace?

Comment: find (?:(?!^)\G|<ADD1<)[^a-zA-Z0-9<]*\K(?:([A-Z])|([a-z])|\d)
 replace (?1X:(?2x:9))

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do a series of replacements here.  Do each replacement by searching in regex mode, and then use the appropriate replacement:

```
[A-Z] -> replace with X
[a-z] -> replace with x
[0-9] -> replace with 9
```

I suggest highlighting the entire address text and then doing the replacement.

Comment: Thanks, but how will it replace with exact number of X's. Please help to provide a syntax.

Comment: @PrabhatSChauhan My regex replaces one character at a time.